# Htaccess Redirect Product Url without Category Path

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1

**Our current product URLs look something like this:**

> https://www.example.com/category1/category2/product.html
>   https://www.example.com/category1/category2/product-2.html

We want them to look like this and have proper 301 redirects set in place:

> https://www.example.com/product.html
>
> https://www.example.com/product-2.html

We are on **Magento 1.9** and I know there is an option to exclude category URL
 under the admin>system>catalog>Catalog>Search engine Optimization> Use Categories Path for Product URLs > NO.

**My question is**, if the "Create Permanent Redirect for URLs if URL Key Changed" is set to yes, will that create a 301 redirect for all of my existing products? Will this be the outcome?
https://www.example.com/category1/category2/product.html will 301 redirect to
https://www.example.com/product.html

&

> https://www.example.com/category1/category2/product-2.html will 301

**redirect to**

> https://www.example.com/product-2.html

If that is not the outcome, is there something within the **.htaccess** file that I could add to make these changes at BULK?